# ionic 3 javascript google map marker onclick error

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 with Javascript Google map API. Here is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {

        this.callOrder();

        //infowindow.setContent(locations[i]['location']);
        //infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
```

this.callOrder(); this is my custom function.

I want to click each and every marker and when I click, this.callOrder(); function will call. But now ***I am getting an error like:***

**"TypeError: this.callOrder is not a function. (In 'this.callOrder()', 'this.callOrder' is undefined)"**

Anyone can give me an idea or a solution?

Comment: Define the callbacks as arrow functions: `(marker, i) => { return () => { ... } }`.

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks.